# Influential observations in Bayesian inference

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

In a (Bayesian in my case) inference, all observations do not contribute equally to the results. Some of them drive substantially the results while others have only negligible effects. When studying hierarchical models it is sometimes difficult to identify which data belong to the first class and to the second class. I guess that one possible empirical approach to identifying them could consist of inferring with a subset of the observations but I do not know how to do that properly. Moreover, I guess that some people have proposed less computationally costly approaches. Thanks for your expertise.

Note: I am not comfortable in the choice of my title. Any suggestion to improve it?

Comment: "Influential observations in Bayesian inference"? In frequentist analyses *influence* is the term for how much the inclusion of a data point affects a fitted model.

Comment: You can always divide the posterior with an observation by the posterior without the observation and "look" either in full parameter space or any marginalisation (interest parameter). The hierarchical nature may make this very challenging.

Comment: There are some papers dedicated to this topic, you could start with https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3500673/